# What command(s) will feed a tab-delimited text file and cut each line to 80 characters?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, columns, tabulation

I've got multiple-line text files of (sometimes) tab-delimited data.  I'd like to output the file so I can glance over it - so I'd like to only see the first 80 characters of each line (I designed the text file to put the important stuff first on each line).

I'd thought I could use cat to read each line of the file, and send each line to the next command in a pipe:

```
cat tabfile | cut -c -80
```

But that seemed broken.  I tried monkeying around, and grep appeared to work - but then I found out that, no it didn't (not every line in the file had 80+ characters) - it appears tabs are counted as single characters by cut.

I tried:

```
cat tabfile | tr \t \040 | cut -c -80
```

Even though that would mangle my data a bit, by eliminating the white-space readability.  But that didn't work.  Neither did:

```
cat tabfile | tr \011 \040 | cut -c -80
```

Maybe I'm using tr wrong?  I've had trouble with tr before, wanting to remove multiple spaces (appears the version of tr that I have access to on this machine has an -s option for squeezing down multiple characters - I may need to play with it more)

I'm sure if I messed around I could use perl, awk or sed, or something to do this.

However, I'd like a solution that uses (POSIX?) regular commands, so that it's as portable as possible.  If I do end up using tr, I'd probably eventually try turning tabs into characters, maybe do a calculation, cut on the calculation, and then turn those characters back into tabs for the output.

It doesn't need to be a single line / entered directly on the command line - a script is fine.

---

More info on tab-files:

I use tab to break fields, because someday I may want to import data into some other program.  So I tend to have only one tab between pieces of content.  But I also use tabs to align things with vertical columns, to aid in readability when looking at the plain text file.  Which means for some pieces of text I pad the end of the content with spaces until I get to where the tab will work in lining up the next field with the ones above and below it.

```
DarkTurquoise           #00CED1         Seas, Skies, Rowboats   Nature
MediumSpringGreen       #00FA9A         Useful for trees        Magic  
Lime                    #00FF00         Only for use on spring chickens and fru$
```

Comment: So you want 80 characters counting the tab width? You could replace tabs with an appropriate count of spaces, then use cut.

Comment: Annnnnd, how do I (easily) expand a single character with multiple characters?  Or, more importantly, with a variable amount of characters (depending on how many other characters are in the line), since I use the tab to line stuff up vertically with differing amounts of info before/after each tab.  Like I said, if I wanted to learn perl/awk/sed I'm sure I could, but I'd like something simple

Comment: You could try `pr` from `coreutils`: `pr -1 -t -l200 -W80 file`. Increase/decrease the page length (number after `-l`) as per your need.

Comment: Don, your suggestion (why isn't it an answer?) gives me a nice error message.  But man says "pr - print files", so looking into that.

Comment: Don, make this an answer and let's discuss it there.  I've got something that looks a lot like yours - mostly the same format, mostly the same flags: -w instead of -W, etc...

Comment: For glancing at the file, the best tool might be `less -S` — views the file truncating lines (to current term size), but lets you scroll right/left to glance at other info!, and understands tabs correctly.  you can also type `-S` to toggle truncation while viewing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for `expand` and/or `unexpand`. It seems you're trying to ensure a `\t`ab width counts as 8 chars rather than the single one. `fold` will do that as well, but it will wrap its input to the next line rather than truncating it. I think you want:

```
expand < input | cut -c -80
```

`expand` and `unexpand` are both [POSIX specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html):

- The `expand` utility shall write files or the standard input to the standard output with `\t`ab characters replaced with one or more *space* characters needed to pad to the next tab stop. Any *backspace* characters shall be copied to the output and cause the column position count for tab stop calculations to be decremented; the column position count shall not be decremented below zero.

Pretty simple. So, here's a look at what this does:

```
unset c i; set --;                                                             
until [ "$((i+=1))" -gt 10 ]; do set -- "$@" "$i" "$i"; done                      
for c in 'tr \\t \ ' expand;  do eval '                                           
    { printf "%*s\t" "$@"; echo; } | 
      tee /dev/fd/2 |'"$c"'| { 
      tee /dev/fd/3 | wc -c >&2; } 3>&1 |
      tee /dev/fd/2 | cut -c -80'
done
```

The `until` loop at top gets a set of data like...

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 ...
```

It `printf`s this with the `%*s` arg padding flag so for each of those in the set `printf` will pad with as many spaces as are in the number of the argument. To each one it appends a `\t`ab character.

All of the `tee`s are used to show the effects of each filter as it is applied.

And the effects are these:

```
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8                9               10
1  2   3    4     5      6       7        8         9         10 
1  2   3    4     5      6       7        8         9         10 
66
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8                9               10
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8                9               10 
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8                
105
```

Those rows are lined up in two sets like...

1. output of `printf ...; echo`
2. output of `tr ...` or `expand`
3. output of `cut`
4. output of `wc`

The top four rows are the results of the `tr` filter - in which each `\t`ab is converted to a single *space*.

And the bottom four the results of the `expand` chain.

Comment: Actually, don't care (too much) if the \t is counted as 8 (5?) or one, just that it's not counted as one and displayed as 8.

Comment: +@anon3202 - makes perfect sense. I understand what you mean - *(and tab stop length is cli option, by the way)* - I just didn't say it as well as I could have. Hopefully you get the gist - as I take it you might have.

Comment: I didn't quite follow the explanation, but monkeying around with expand shows that expand is definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Since the tabs are more for alignment than delimitation, one way could be to use `column` and then `cut`:

```
column -s '\t' -t <some-file | cut -c -80
```

It seems `column` is not POSIX. It is part of the BSD utils on Ubuntu, so I assume it is fairly cross platform.

Comment: Using `column` this way OP wouldn't even need the manually adding spaces to align.

Answer (score 1):

Don's suggestion in comments was a good start.

This is what I needed to make it (mostly) work:

```
pr +1 -1 -t -m -l1000 -w 80 tabfile
```

The `-m` was needed to make the `-w` flag take effect on a single column.  The man page could use some re-writing to indicate that.

When trying a workaround, I found that `pr` outputs `\t` characters, so feeding its results to `cut` resulted in the same problem.

`-1` (the column flag) specifically says in the man page:

> This option should not be used with -m.

However, without this option `pr` truncates lines willy-nilly, at much shorter than specified length.

`pr` also inserts a space before (or after?) every word in a field (i.e. every place I have a single space, has two after processing).  If there are too many words, the inserted spaces ignore the `-w` restriction (creating wrap-around).  But, curiously, otherwise-non-tab-delimited (i.e. whitespace arranged) 'columns' stay lined up.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ $0 = substr($0, 1, 80) }1' file
```

Based on [Chris Down's answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107092).

Comment: Bites it on the \t's - But that link looks promising

Answer (score 0):

One utility that should be truly display-width aware is `fold`: unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have an option to discard instead of wrap. Although it's probably horribly inefficient, you could however do something like

```
while read -r line; do fold -w80 <<< "$line" | head -n1; done < file
```