# Trim lines to a specific length

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file with many lines, and I want to trim each line to be 80 characters in length. How could I do this?

I have already filtered out lines shorter than 80 characters, so now I'm left with a file that has lines 80+ characters in length and I want to trim each line so that all are exactly 80. In other words I want to preserve the first 80 characters in each line and remove the rest of the line.

Comment: Are the proposed solutions not working for you?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro You have made this a duplicate of an invalid (off-topic) question, Interesting !!. Yes there are [other questions that may match the concept of duplicate a bit better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175852/what-commands-will-feed-a-tab-delimited-text-file-and-cut-each-line-to-80-char), but not that one.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `cut` command:

```
cut -c -80 file
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '.{80}' file
```

Comment: I only want to cut each line in the file to 80, the file itself has thousands of lines, each line longer than 80 characters.

Comment: @mah That is what this command does.

Comment: Well, not exactly, cut counts bytes (not characters).

Comment: @Isaac:  True for GNU cut

Comment: @Isaac: Also apparently GNU has fixed that in later versions of coreutils

Comment: Testing on *cut (GNU coreutils) 8.28*, it cuts on bytes, is there a newer version available?

Comment: I don't think it was ever broken on BSD cut and it cuts by character for me with coreutils 8.28

Comment: Trying echo áááááááááá\ éééééééééé{,,} | tee /dev/stderr | cut -c -80` prints 
`áááááááááá éééééééééé áááááááááá éééééééééé áááááááááá éééééééééé
áááááááááá éééééééééé áááááááááá éééééééé�` Which looks broken to me.

Comment: Are you using glibc? What OS?

Comment: Alright yeah it's not working with gnu cut afterall, bsd cut works fine though.  macos

Comment: fwiw, that grep syntax just reformatted the output to 80 columns without cutting it. λ awk '{print substr($0,1,80)}' did what I was looking for. Thanks all.

Comment: Here is fix for grep: `grep -Eo '^.{80}' file`

Answer (score 10):

Using **AWK:**

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,80)}' file.txt
```

Using **cut:**

```
 cut -c -80 file.txt
```

Using **colrm:**

```
colrm 81 file.txt
```

Using **sed:**

```
sed 's/^\(.\{80\}\).*$/\1/' file.txt
```

Using **grep:**

```
grep -Eo '.{80}' file.txt
```

Comment: awk worked for me. grep did not. I didn't try the others. Thanks for the solution I needed!

Comment: Could you have meant `'^.{80}'` in your `grep` RegExp?

Answer (score 5):

To cut (truncate) each line of the file (and have the output in the present console) use:

```
cut -c -80 infile               # cut only counts bytes (fail with utf8)
grep -o '^.\{1,80\}' infile
sed 's/\(^.\{1,80\}\).*/\1/' infile
```

If what you want is to insert a newline at the 80 character and split each line longer than 80 characters into more lines, use:

```
fold -w 80 infile            # fold, like cut, counts bytes.
```

If you want to split only at spaces (whole words), use:

```
fold -sw 80 infile
```

For all the solutions above, redirect to some other file like `>outfile` (do not use the same name, that will not work) at the end of any command to store the result in `outfile`. Example:

```
fold -sw 80 infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{80\}\).*$/\1/' file
```

With `cut`:

```
cut -c -80 file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (née Perl6)**

```
~$ raku -ne 'put ~$0 if m/ ^^(. ** 80) /;'
```

OUTPUT:

```
the of and to in a is that for it as was with be by on not he i this are or his
the of and to in a is that for it as was with be by on not he i this are or his
the of and to in a is that for it as was with be by on not he i this are or his
the of and to in a is that for it as was with be by on not he i this are or his
[TRUNCATED]
```

The code above return the first 80 characters of a line (the `^^` zero-width assertion means "start-of-line"). If the line is too short, nothing is returned. To return *UP TO* 80 characters, use the form `** 1..80`.

Numbering captures starts with `$0`. Get a readout of the number of characters returned by adding `.chars` to the `~$0` capture variable:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put ~$0.chars if m/ ^^(. ** 80) /;' ~/top50.txt
80
80
80
80
[TRUNCATED]
```

HTH.

https://raku.org